# error getting while trying to display xy graph in jsp page

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, graph

hi i have database table job_status having fields date,time and speed.I wanted to display a a graph between speed and time on a jsp page but i am getting errors and so posting the question here.Please help me

```
<%// required packages  %>
<%@ page import ="DB.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.awt.Image" %>
<%@ page import="java.awt.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@ page import="java.awt.BasicStroke"%>
<%@ page import ="org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame"%>
<%@ page import="java.io.*" %>
<%@ page import="java.io.File"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.axis.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.entity.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.labels.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.category.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.urls.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.category.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.general.*" %>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.Minute"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.Hour"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYItemRenderer"%>
<%@ page import="org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer"%>
 <%@ page import=  "java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import  ="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import = "java.sql.Statement" %>
 <%@ page import=  "javax.servlet.*" %>
<%@ page import  ="javax.servlet.http.*" %>

<%@ page import="java.awt.image.BufferedImage"%>
<%
 try
 {
 File image = File.createTempFile("image", "tmp");

 //chart class instance
Fms fm = new Fms("Graph");

JFreeChart chart = fm.createChart(fm.dataset);
 ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(image, chart, 500, 400);
//get input stream
 FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(image);
//output stream foe returning chart as image
 OutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
 long fileLength;
 byte[] byteStream;
 fileLength = image.length();
 byteStream = new byte[(int)fileLength];
//read chart image
 fileInStream.read(byteStream, 0, (int)fileLength);
//returns chart image whenever called
 response.setContentType("image/png");
 response.setContentLength((int)fileLength);
 response.setHeader("Cache-Control","no-store,no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
 fileInStream.close();
 outStream.write(byteStream);
 outStream.flush();
 outStream.close();
 }
 catch (IOException e)
 {
 System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
 }
%>
<%! public class Fms extends ApplicationFrame {  
//Main class
   XYDataset dataset= null;
   public Fms(final String title) {
        super(title);
      dataset= createDataset();
        final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
        final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
        chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));
        chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
        setContentPane(chartPanel);
    }
//chart creation method
   JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
            "Speed Chart",
            "Time",
            "Speed",
            dataset,
            true,
            true,
            false
        );
        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
       final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
        plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
        final XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
        if (renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
            final StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
            rr.setShapesFilled(true);
            renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
            renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
           }      
        final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
        axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM"));
        try{
        final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
(new StandardEntityCollection());
final File file1 = new File("/barchart.png");
ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        return chart;
    }  
//data set generation method
    private XYDataset createDataset() {
        final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
        dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
        final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
         int str = 0;
         int i =0,j= 0 ;
         String str1 = null;
        try{         
            DataBaseConnection db= new DataBaseConnection();
      Connection con=db.connet();
      PreparedStatement st;  
      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      String query = "Select * from Job_Status";
      stmt.executeQuery(query);
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);      
           while( rs.next() )
        {                
         str1= rs.getString("Time");
         String sa = str1.substring(11,13);
         String ha = str1.substring(14,16);
        str= rs.getInt("Speed");
        j=Integer.parseInt(sa);
        i=Integer.parseInt(ha);
        String date = rs.getString("Date");
        String y = date.substring(0,4);
         String m = date.substring(5,7);
          String d = date.substring(8,10);
         s1.add(new Minute(i, j, Integer.parseInt(d), Integer.parseInt(m), Integer.parseInt(y)), str);
          }
          }
          catch(Exception e)
          {            
          }
         System.out.println(str1.substring(11,13));
          System.out.println(str1.substring(14,16)+"\t"+str1);                
        dataset.addSeries(s1);  
        return dataset;
    }
    }
%>
```

error is

```
HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP:

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [19] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.ui.ApplicationFrame resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [31] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.data.time.Minute resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [32] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.data.time.Hour resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [33] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeries resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [34] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.data.time.TimeSeriesCollection resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [35] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.data.xy.XYDataset resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [36] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [37] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.StandardXYItemRenderer resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [38] in the generated java file: [/home/sukanth/workspace1/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/work/Catalina/localhost/project1/org/apache/jsp/chart_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. org.jfree.chart.renderer.xy.XYItemRenderer resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 73 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ApplicationFrame cannot be resolved to a type
70:  System.err.println("Problem occurred creating chart.");
71:  }
72: %>
73: <%! public class Fms extends ApplicationFrame {  
74: //Main class
75:    XYDataset dataset= null;
76:    public Fms(final String title) {


An error occurred at line: 75 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
XYDataset cannot be resolved to a type
72: %>
73: <%! public class Fms extends ApplicationFrame {  
74: //Main class
75:    XYDataset dataset= null;
76:    public Fms(final String title) {
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();


An error occurred at line: 78 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
dataset cannot be resolved to a variable
75:    XYDataset dataset= null;
76:    public Fms(final String title) {
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();
79:         final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
80:         final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
81:         chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));


An error occurred at line: 78 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
The method createDataset() is undefined for the type chart_jsp.Fms
75:    XYDataset dataset= null;
76:    public Fms(final String title) {
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();
79:         final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
80:         final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
81:         chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));


An error occurred at line: 79 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
JFreeChart cannot be resolved to a type
76:    public Fms(final String title) {
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();
79:         final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
80:         final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
81:         chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));
82:         chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);


An error occurred at line: 79 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
dataset cannot be resolved to a variable
76:    public Fms(final String title) {
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();
79:         final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
80:         final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
81:         chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));
82:         chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);


An error occurred at line: 80 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartPanel cannot be resolved to a type
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();
79:         final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
80:         final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
81:         chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));
82:         chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
83:         setContentPane(chartPanel);


An error occurred at line: 80 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartPanel cannot be resolved to a type
77:         super(title);
78:       dataset= createDataset();
79:         final JFreeChart chart = createChart(dataset);
80:         final ChartPanel chartPanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
81:         chartPanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(700, 570));
82:         chartPanel.setMouseZoomable(true, false);
83:         setContentPane(chartPanel);


An error occurred at line: 86 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
JFreeChart cannot be resolved to a type
83:         setContentPane(chartPanel);
84:     }
85: //chart creation method
86:    JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
87:         final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
88:             "Speed Chart",
89:             "Time",


An error occurred at line: 86 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
XYDataset cannot be resolved to a type
83:         setContentPane(chartPanel);
84:     }
85: //chart creation method
86:    JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
87:         final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
88:             "Speed Chart",
89:             "Time",


An error occurred at line: 87 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
JFreeChart cannot be resolved to a type
84:     }
85: //chart creation method
86:    JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
87:         final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
88:             "Speed Chart",
89:             "Time",
90:             "Speed",


An error occurred at line: 87 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartFactory cannot be resolved
84:     }
85: //chart creation method
86:    JFreeChart createChart(final XYDataset dataset) {
87:         final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createTimeSeriesChart(
88:             "Speed Chart",
89:             "Time",
90:             "Speed",


An error occurred at line: 97 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
XYPlot cannot be resolved to a type
94:             false
95:         );
96:         chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);
97:        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
98:         plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
99:         plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
100:         plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);


An error occurred at line: 103 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
XYItemRenderer cannot be resolved to a type
100:         plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);
101:         plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
102:         plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
103:         final XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
104:         if (renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
105:             final StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
106:             rr.setShapesFilled(true);


An error occurred at line: 104 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
StandardXYItemRenderer cannot be resolved to a type
101:         plot.setDomainCrosshairVisible(true);
102:         plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
103:         final XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
104:         if (renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
105:             final StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
106:             rr.setShapesFilled(true);
107:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));


An error occurred at line: 105 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
StandardXYItemRenderer cannot be resolved to a type
102:         plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
103:         final XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
104:         if (renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
105:             final StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
106:             rr.setShapesFilled(true);
107:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
108:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(1.0f));


An error occurred at line: 105 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
StandardXYItemRenderer cannot be resolved to a type
102:         plot.setRangeCrosshairVisible(false);
103:         final XYItemRenderer renderer = plot.getRenderer();
104:         if (renderer instanceof StandardXYItemRenderer) {
105:             final StandardXYItemRenderer rr = (StandardXYItemRenderer) renderer;
106:             rr.setShapesFilled(true);
107:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
108:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(1.0f));


An error occurred at line: 110 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
DateAxis cannot be resolved to a type
107:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
108:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
109:            }      
110:         final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
111:         axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM"));
112:         try{
113:         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo


An error occurred at line: 110 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
DateAxis cannot be resolved to a type
107:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(0, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
108:             renderer.setSeriesStroke(1, new BasicStroke(1.0f));
109:            }      
110:         final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
111:         axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM"));
112:         try{
113:         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo


An error occurred at line: 113 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartRenderingInfo cannot be resolved to a type
110:         final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
111:         axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM"));
112:         try{
113:         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
114: (new StandardEntityCollection());
115: final File file1 = new File("/barchart.png");
116: ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);


An error occurred at line: 113 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartRenderingInfo cannot be resolved to a type
110:         final DateAxis axis = (DateAxis) plot.getDomainAxis();
111:         axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM"));
112:         try{
113:         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
114: (new StandardEntityCollection());
115: final File file1 = new File("/barchart.png");
116: ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);


An error occurred at line: 114 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
StandardEntityCollection cannot be resolved to a type
111:         axis.setDateFormatOverride(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM"));
112:         try{
113:         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
114: (new StandardEntityCollection());
115: final File file1 = new File("/barchart.png");
116: ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
117:         }catch(Exception e){}


An error occurred at line: 116 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartUtilities cannot be resolved
113:         final ChartRenderingInfo info = new ChartRenderingInfo
114: (new StandardEntityCollection());
115: final File file1 = new File("/barchart.png");
116: ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(file1, chart, 600, 400, info);
117:         }catch(Exception e){}
118:         return chart;
119:     }  


An error occurred at line: 121 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
XYDataset cannot be resolved to a type
118:         return chart;
119:     }  
120: //data set generation method
121:     private XYDataset createDataset() {
122:         final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
123:         dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
124:         final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);


An error occurred at line: 122 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
TimeSeriesCollection cannot be resolved to a type
119:     }  
120: //data set generation method
121:     private XYDataset createDataset() {
122:         final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
123:         dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
124:         final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
125:          int str = 0;


An error occurred at line: 122 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
TimeSeriesCollection cannot be resolved to a type
119:     }  
120: //data set generation method
121:     private XYDataset createDataset() {
122:         final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
123:         dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
124:         final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
125:          int str = 0;


An error occurred at line: 124 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
TimeSeries cannot be resolved to a type
121:     private XYDataset createDataset() {
122:         final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
123:         dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
124:         final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
125:          int str = 0;
126:          int i =0,j= 0 ;
127:          String str1 = null;


An error occurred at line: 124 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
TimeSeries cannot be resolved to a type
121:     private XYDataset createDataset() {
122:         final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
123:         dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
124:         final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
125:          int str = 0;
126:          int i =0,j= 0 ;
127:          String str1 = null;


An error occurred at line: 124 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
Minute cannot be resolved to a type
121:     private XYDataset createDataset() {
122:         final TimeSeriesCollection dataset = new TimeSeriesCollection();
123:         dataset.setDomainIsPointsInTime(true);      
124:         final TimeSeries s1 = new TimeSeries("Series 1", Minute.class);
125:          int str = 0;
126:          int i =0,j= 0 ;
127:          String str1 = null;


An error occurred at line: 148 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
Minute cannot be resolved to a type
145:         String y = date.substring(0,4);
146:          String m = date.substring(5,7);
147:           String d = date.substring(8,10);
148:          s1.add(new Minute(i, j, Integer.parseInt(d), Integer.parseInt(m), Integer.parseInt(y)), str);
149:           }
150:           }
151:           catch(Exception e)


An error occurred at line: 46 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
JFreeChart cannot be resolved to a type
43:  //chart class instance
44: Fms fm = new Fms("Graph");
45: 
46: JFreeChart chart = fm.createChart(fm.dataset);
47:  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(image, chart, 500, 400);
48: //get input stream
49:  FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(image);


An error occurred at line: 46 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
dataset cannot be resolved or is not a field
43:  //chart class instance
44: Fms fm = new Fms("Graph");
45: 
46: JFreeChart chart = fm.createChart(fm.dataset);
47:  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(image, chart, 500, 400);
48: //get input stream
49:  FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(image);


An error occurred at line: 47 in the jsp file: /chart.jsp
ChartUtilities cannot be resolved
44: Fms fm = new Fms("Graph");
45: 
46: JFreeChart chart = fm.createChart(fm.dataset);
47:  ChartUtilities.saveChartAsPNG(image, chart, 500, 400);
48: //get input stream
49:  FileInputStream fileInStream = new FileInputStream(image);
50: //output stream foe returning chart as image


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:331)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:468)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.37 logs.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.37
```

**edit** there are no **Compilations errors** there are only runtime errors

Answer (score 0):

Please please please write this as a servlet.
You will get multiple benefits including the IDE showing you compile errors.

You state "there are no Compilations errors there are only runtime errors" but the errors are compile errors, happening when the jsp is attempted to be compiled.